# Multiple NSFetchedResultsController in one TableView

Tags: ios, core-data

I am trying to populate a tableview from CoreData using NSFetchedResultController.
The issue is that I want to use 2 entities to populate the NSFetchedResultController

One of the Entities is called Folder and the other is Documents.
The relationship between these entities is implemented on the server side.

How can I add mutiple NSFetchedResultController in one class/TableView?

Or is there a better option that I can expliore.

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on how you implement the `UITableViewDataSource` methods.  You'll lose some of the niceties, but it should be feasible.

I sometimes swap between showing two different entity types (frc = fetched results controller), …

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
  NSInteger n = [[[self frcForTable:tableView] sections] count];
  return n;
}
```

If you're co-mingling the results from the fetched results controller, the complexity will depend upon how you are doing that.  If you put one type at the top, one at the bottom, it should be easier, than if you want to interlace them.

*Edit*:

Implement the data source methods to "mash" the two results together:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
  NSInteger count1 = [[frc1 sections] count];
  NSInteger count2 = [[frc2 sections] count];
  return count1+count2;
}
```

of course, if you want one section, then you wouldn't need the above,

Comment: Yes I want to put one type at top and one type at bottom

Comment: How will you implement the cells in the table view

Comment: If the cell types will be drastically different just use two different cell types.  Each should have it's own unique `reuseIdentifier`.